# Is there any other way to swap address of pointers to interchange value?

Tags: c, pointers, swap

Is there any other way to swap address of pointers to interchange value ?

Below is one way to do the same. Here we are not changing values saved on address.

```
void Change_Address( int *&p, int *&pt)
{
 int *pp;
 pp = p;
 p = pt;
 pt= pp;
}
int main(void)
{
   int a =3, b = 4, *p, *p1;
   p = &a; p1 = &b;    
   printf("Values Before interchange %d %d\n", *p, *p1);
   Change_Address(p, p1);
   printf("Values after interchange %d %d", *p, *p1);    
  getch();     
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not `C`, this is `C++`. There are no references in `C`.

Comment: It's not good, it's not important, it's not C, it's not a question, and it doesn't belong on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Rohan this is C question.

Comment: @JimBalter Why not you can give any other example to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Your code uses references which are `C++`, in `C` you would have to use pointer to pointer :

```
void Change_Address( int **p, int **pt)
{
 int *pp;
 pp = *p;
 *p = *pt;
 *pt= pp;
}

int main(void)
{
   int a =3, b = 4, *p, *p1;
   p = &a; p1 = &b;    
   printf("Values Before interchange %d %d\n", *p, *p1);
   Change_Address(&p, &p1);
   printf("Values after interchange %d %d", *p, *p1);    
   getch();     
   return 0;
}
```